# Edit CSV data using PHP and HTML table

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

I have a CSV file that contains many data.

I use `PHP` to read and view it in WEB. I need to have a functionality like `ADD, EDIT and DELETE`. I already done the ADD using the `a` or `append`. I will add data in HTML Table and automatically it will add also in CSV file. I didn't use database here.

My problem now is the EDIT. What if i want to edit some data in CSV file using the HTML Table and like the ADD i want to automatically update it to my CSV file. How can i do that?

I already tried the `w, w+, r+` but it didn't work. By the way I am using CODEIGNITER here.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep the logic on server and do all the csv rendering eventdriven.
Here you have a good csv lib: https://github.com/goodby/csv

So the process would be something like this:

- Client: Load csv preformated (via php) from server and display in html
- Client: Do MVVM bindings etc.
- Client: If an event is called (like add, update etc.) send
  eventrequest to server
- Server: Recieve event -> Process (with transactions if needed) -> reformat csv, save it
  and send back to client
- Client: Retrieve and apply MvvM bindings

Otherwise you need redundant csv logic in client and server whats not a fine approach.
Do you know what I mean or should I do you an example?

The csv library supports complex csv binding and easy appending like:

```
$csv = new parseCSV();
$csv->parse('yourcsv.csv');
$csv->data[1] = array('updatekey' => 'new Value');
$csv->save();
```

Client side example:

```
//retrieve your csv (view rendered or async with ajax
var csv;

var mutableDataArray = $.csv.toArray(csv);

//do manipulation here
//for example
mutableDataArray[0].name = 'A new name to first record';

//serialize back
var newCsv = "";
for(var i in mutableDataArray) {
    var data = mutableDataArray[i].join(",");
    newCsv += i < mutableDataArray[i].length ? data + "\n" : data;
}

//do something with newCsv
```

Comment: I have already read and viewed the CSV File in WEB using. I can also add new data at the EOF, my problem now is the EDIT.

Comment: Can you give me a example for that?

Comment: If you prefere to manipulate the csv on client (I guess you mean that with "WEB using" right?) you should deserialize the csv into a javascript array (use: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/) manipulate the array and serialize it back to csv.

Comment: Added an example for client side manipulation (but I still recommend you the eventdriven approach :P)